# What information is transferred if I copy-paste an image from a graphics software?

Tags: clipboard

If I copy a certain vector or "curve" graphic or drawing from, say, GIMP to a blank page of Inkscape, then in the meanwhile, what information is stored in the clipboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image is nothing but a matrix, with each value representing the colour of a respective pixel. When you copy one image (or layer from GIMP, Photoshop, etc.), basically you are copying the matrix to your destination. That's what the clipboard stores.

In cases where you have more complex objects copied (eg real vectors, like the ones you can manipulate on Adobe Illustrator), they're still a matrix, but the operation is just applied on a determined member of the vector/matrix, and not on it's whole.

Answer (score 1):

Geo's answer is spot-on, but I wanted to add some clarifications... The clipboard store can hold all sorts of information...from raw binary data to (most commonly), user-readable text. It is up to the application to decide what data should be sent and received from the store and what this data means. One file manager (i.e. nautilus) preforms copy-paste operations of all files by scanning the clipboard store for "file:///" links, while another might preform the same copy action on files by reading the name and data of the selected file and putting it in the store-stack during a "copy" operation, and writing the name and data from the store to a new file during a "paste" operation. The same goes for image manipulation programs; one might store RGB matrix values of the selection on the clipboard while another image program might store it on the clipboard in a proprietary format, there may be standards, but it's all up to the application.

Edit: I forgot to mention that most Graphical toolkits and even some display servers come with built-in clipboard handling functions that allow generic copy-paste functions to work on a programs various widgets (such as a text box or file upload box) that don't have these interfaces explicitly defined by the programmer.